# MSVC2008, how to turn off "sound" from "Find-and-replace" dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

The MSVC 2008 IDE plays an audible "sound/bell" upon completion of the dialog for "Find-and-replace".

It's irritating -- how do you shut this off?

(I need the PC sound otherwise enabled.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into the Windows 'control panel > hardware > sound > change system sounds' and go into the list. It's probably 'Exclamation' or 'Default Beep' though there are many possibilities. You can disable/change the sound here.

Comment: This worked -- it is the `Asterisk` sound (echo'd by the "find-and-replace" dialog).  Very disappointing I could not turn this off within MSVC itself (and had to do it for the whole windows system).

Comment: Yeah, while writing the answer I thought "it'd be nice to do it selectively" but without going to extremes I figured it was going to be tricky. At least you can still listen to music and get *most* sounds with just 'Asterisk' off.

Comment: Actually, just a thought... if you have a modern mixer you can click on the volume icon, then mixer, and you can *selectively* disable sounds for applications. This is on Windows 7 for me, just a thought.